# Rescue Timeout::Error from Redis Gem (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, exception, redis, rescue

I need to rescue a `Timeout::Error` raised from a the Redis library but i'm running into a problem, rescuing that specific class doesn't seem to work.

```
begin
  Redis.new( { :host => "127.0.0.X" } )
rescue Timeout::Error => ex
end

=> Timeout::Error: Timeout::Error from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@gowalla/gems/redis-2.2.0/lib/redis/connection/hiredis.rb:23:in `connect'
```

When i try to rescue `Exception` it still doesn't work

```
begin
  Redis.new( { :host => "127.0.0.X" } )
rescue Exception => ex
end

=> Timeout::Error: Timeout::Error from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@gowalla/gems/redis-2.2.0/lib/redis/connection/hiredis.rb:23:in `connect'
```

If i try to raise the exception manually, i can rescue it but don't know why i can't rescue it when it's called from within the Redis Gem (2.2.0).

```
begin
  raise Timeout::Error
rescue Timeout::Error => ex
  puts ex 
end

Timeout::Error
=> nil
```

Any clue how to rescue this exception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You ran this code in irb, right?  The exception you are getting is not actually being raised by `Redis.new`.  It is being raised by the `inspect` method, which irb calls to show you the value of the expression you just typed.

Just look at the stack trace (I shortened the paths to make it legible):

```
ruby-1.8.7-p330 :009 >   Redis.new(:host => "google.com")
Timeout::Error: time's up!
    from /.../SystemTimer-1.2.3/lib/system_timer/concurrent_timer_pool.rb:63:in `trigger_next_expired_timer_at'
    from /.../SystemTimer-1.2.3/lib/system_timer/concurrent_timer_pool.rb:68:in `trigger_next_expired_timer'
    from /.../SystemTimer-1.2.3/lib/system_timer.rb:85:in `install_ruby_sigalrm_handler'
    from /..../lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
    from /.../SystemTimer-1.2.3/lib/system_timer.rb:83:in `install_ruby_sigalrm_handler'
    from /.../redis-2.2.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:26:in `call'
    from /.../redis-2.2.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:26:in `initialize'
    from /.../redis-2.2.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:26:in `new'
    from /.../redis-2.2.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:26:in `connect'
    from /.../SystemTimer-1.2.3/lib/system_timer.rb:60:in `timeout_after'
    from /.../redis-2.2.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:115:in `with_timeout'
    from /.../redis-2.2.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:25:in `connect'
    from /.../redis-2.2.2/lib/redis/client.rb:227:in `establish_connection'
    from /.../redis-2.2.2/lib/redis/client.rb:23:in `connect'
    from /.../redis-2.2.2/lib/redis/client.rb:247:in `ensure_connected'
    from /.../redis-2.2.2/lib/redis/client.rb:137:in `process'
... 2 levels...
    from /.../redis-2.2.2/lib/redis/client.rb:46:in `call'
    from /.../redis-2.2.2/lib/redis.rb:90:in `info'
    from /..../lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
    from /.../redis-2.2.2/lib/redis.rb:89:in `info'
    from /.../redis-2.2.2/lib/redis.rb:1075:in `inspect'
    from /..../lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
    from /.../redis-2.2.2/lib/redis.rb:1074:in `inspect'
    from /..../lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:310:in `output_value'
    from /..../lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:159:in `eval_input'
    from /..../lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:271:in `signal_status'
    from /..../lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:155:in `eval_input'
    from /..../lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:154:in `eval_input'
    from /..../lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:71:in `start'
    from /..../lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:70:in `catch'
    from /..../lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:70:in `start'
    from /..../bin/irb:17
```

As you can see above, the exception occurs inside `inspect`, not `Redis.new`.  When you call `inspect` on a Redis object, instead of just printing out its state it actually does a lot of things.  In this case, `inspect` attempts to connect to the server and throws an exception when that times out.  This seems like a very bad design to me and maybe we should file a bug report to the maintainers of the Redis gem.

This leads to some interesting behavior in IRB:

- Typing `Redis.new(:host => "google.com")` results in an exception as shown above
- Typing `Redis.new(:host => "google.com"); 'hello'` results in '`=> "hello"`'

If you want to catch this exception, try calling `ensure_connected` inside your begin/rescue/end block.

Comment: In my case ( see above question, if my edit is approved ), this answer help me figure out that IRB's `insect` is source of problem.

Thank you, Devid!