# Exception not caught by rescue block

Tags: ruby, exception, redis, rescue

The problem is in relation to the `radis-rb` gem.

The exception is not caught by my rescue block and my app goes down.

My code:

```
begin
  redis = Redis.new 
  puts "WTF?"
rescue Exception
  puts "Exception"
end
```

If `redis` is down, the message *WTF?* is exposed.

It happens with or without the Exception statement.

Why is the exception not raised to my rescue block?

Comment: Please [don't ever rescue from Exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048173/why-is-it-bad-style-to-rescue-exception-e-in-ruby)!

Comment: @Andrew: While that's true, it's not really helpful in this case because `Errno::ECONNREFUSED` should inherit from `Exception` (at least if the Gem doesn't replace it...). As I read it from the answer, OP has already tried a plain `rescue`: "It is still so with/without Exception statement."

Comment: @NiklasB. I know, but it's still not a good idea to rescue from it in the first place (hence this being a comment).

Comment: On a more related note, is that call to `Redis.new` actually in the stacktrace from the exception?

Comment: Just rescue from Errno::ECONNREFUSED

Comment: `WTF?` printed. I update my question. Rescue from Errno::ECONNREFUSED - result is the same

Comment: So what is the backtrace ? Sounds like the call to Redis.new isn't what is throwing the exception

Comment: Thank you for conversation! Exception is raised (in IRB) when IRB try to print the result of `Redis.new` call. Exception isn't raised (in script) because `redis ruby gem` not raise exception if redis service is down.

Comment: @PaulChechetin Until you provide the backtrace from the exception and verify that your code provided is a part of the backtrace, no one can answer your question.

Comment: The problem is has been solved, thank you!

Comment: @PaulChechetin perhaps you should extract your answer from the question and answer the question yourself, which is quite reasonable

Comment: @defaye I can't do that because my reputation is too few. I will do that later ( after about 8 hour )

Comment: My bad: thought you had 8 hours :)

Comment: @defaye I'm so sorry for my broken English.

Comment: @PaulChechetin it's there to help others and you. Nothing personal or bad. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem myself (with help from the community and comments).

The exception occurred in IRB only.

The reason of one is IRB's `inspect` call when IRB try to print result of `Redis.new`.

In the script (not IRB), the exception doesn't occur because `Redis.new` does not raise an exception if the `Redis` service is down.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035054/rescue-timeouterror-from-redis-gem-ruby) helped to solve my problem.

Comment: Oh man, that's really bad API design. Glad you figured it out!